# How do I write html for form with multiple questions that use radio input type?

Tags: javascript, html, radio-button, vuejs3

I have this quiz in multiple choice format where users can select one option per question and submit their answers at the end. This example shows what I'm trying achieve: [Example code w3school][1]

The problem I'm having is that selecting an option on a question de-selects any previous selection, meaning only one option can be selected for the entire quiz.

This is a section of my form template:

```
<form @submit.prevent="submit">
<div v-for="question in questions" :key="question.id">
 <jet-label :for="question.question" :value="question.question" class="font-bold text-lg" />
     <div v-for="option in question.options" :key="option.id">
        <jet-label :for="option.option" :value="option.option" />
        <input :id="option.id" type="radio" :value="option.option" 
        :name="option.question_id" v-model="form.options" />
     </div>
</div>
<div class="flex items-center justify-end mt-4">
    <jet-button class="ml-4" :class="{ 'opacity-25': form.processing }" 
     :disabled="form.processing">
       Submit
     </jet-button>
</div>
</form>
```

And this is the JS to handle user selection binding:

```
<script setup>
...
import { useForm } from '@inertiajs/inertia-vue3'

defineProps({
    questions: Array
})

const form = useForm({
    options: []
})

...
</script>
```

The issue probably is that inputs are seen as belonging to one group. How can I group the inputs based on the question id so that the select/deselect radio action is per question?
[1]: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_input_type_radio

Comment: Hi @CesarePolonara, I already did that by setting the name attribute based on the question. name="option.question.id" is the same for all options under a question but different for options under other questions. Is that what you mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`v-model="form.options"` seems to be the problem, all inputs have the same model.
Everytime a radio is selected it overwrites the `this.options` with the option value.

Try:

```
v-model="form.options[option.question_id]"
```

if that dosen't work try to add a custom event handler with `@change`

BTW: *`option.question_id` is a weird data structure it meight be better to have the id in the question object, because it seems the options lay in an array inside the question object*

Comment: Thanks for this @Fabian. The build process errors out with your suggested v-model modification. Regarding your comment on option.question_id, the question object has an id. The query to get my questions from the database uses the 'with method' to pull the options associated with each question.

Comment: What does the error message say? I did a test with mock data and it worked that way. I forgot a " in my answer, edited it

Comment: VueCompilerError: Error parsing JavaScript expression: Unexpected token, VueCompilerError: v-model value must be a valid JavaScript member expression in reference to the array, [].

Comment: You're correct, it did work! Thanks. Problem was that just added an empty array: v-model="form.options[]" as a quick check and that errored out. Adding the complete v-model worked and I can select all options.

Comment: Quick follow up question @FabianLehmann, if you don't mind, the options array for the v-model has an index entry of 'undefined', why is that?

Comment: I can't tell without an example, sorry. Does the array only have one index which is undefined?

Comment: Yes, just the first one. But changing my data type to an object rather than an array resolved that and I don't know why. prop: {} instead of prop: [].